# mapping external status to internal status + providing multiple "representations" of the status

Tags: c#

I need to map status values from an external source:

- external source status == 1 -->  internal source status == 2     =="NEW"
- external source status == 5 -->  internal source status == 7     =="PROCESSED"

So, I sometimes need to represent the internal status as integer or string..I think I should do this in a single function, as the status, regardless of the dataType, is representing the same thing.

My question, do I create a function that takes the external source status as an arg, then returns a key value pair? I don't want to create 2 functions when one would do.

Ta,

yogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a class representing an internal status

```
public class InternalStatus
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can build a dictionary by taking the external ID as key

```
private Dictionary<int, InternalStatus> _map = new Dictionary<int, InternalStatus>();
```

Add the mapping

```
_map.Add(1, new InternalStatus { ID = 2, Name = "NEW" });
_map.Add(5, new InternalStatus { ID = 7, Name = "PROCESSED" });
```

Now you can look up a mapping like this:

```
int externalStatusID = 5;
InternalStatus internalStatus;
if (_map.TryGetValue(externalStatusID, out internalStatus)) {
    Console.WriteLine("Internal status ID = {0}, Name = {1}",
        internalStatus.ID, internalStatus.Name);
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("Status not found!");
}
```

Comment: Ta for all the replies folks.I went with Olivier's.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is logically two different `enum` types that map the same values to different integers:

```
public enum ExternalSourceStatus
{
    NEW = 1,
    PROCESSED = 5,
}
public enum InternalSourceStatus
{
    NEW = 2,
    PROCESSED = 7,
}
```

You can then create a dictionary to map the external status to the internal status:

```
var statusMap = new Dictionary<ExternalSourceStatus, InternalSourceStatus>()
{
    {ExternalSourceStatus.NEW, InternalSourceStatus.NEW},
    {ExternalSourceStatus.PROCESSED, InternalSourceStatus.PROCESSED},
};
```

(You could build this dictionary at runtime, if your status' are *really* big; for sufficiently small enumerations, it's likely easier to just build it yourself.)

Comment: An enum is not suited if a text output has to be generated for the user. The enum constants are bound to the rules for identifiers. E.g. they must have PascalCasing, have no spaces and so on.  Where as the user output is culture specific.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes If he actually needs that flexibility, then sure, this may not be the best option, but he may not be in a position where that is a requirement of his application.